# javascript bootstrap Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked through the numerous questions others have posed about an accordion style collapsable set of panels but I haven't been able to find one in which the panels remain separate and do not retain a header of sorts.

I am looking to have numerous buttons on one side and on the other, a panel to be displayed when a button is clicked. I want only one panel to ever be displayed at a time. I am using BootStrap CSS Framework (love it).

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please help me fine tune my code. I do not understand where I have gone wrong.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#overview" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="overview" data-parent="#accordion">Overview</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="view1" data-parent="#accordion">View 1</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="view2" data-parent="#accordion">View 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default collapse in" id="overview">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Overview</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default collapse" id="view1">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">View 1</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default collapse" id="view2">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">View 2</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? I can assume this "doesn't work", but what behavior are you expecting, and what *does* it do? If you can create a Stack Snippet or JSFiddle demonstrating either case, it would be helpful.

Comment: Great idea! I didn't even realize I could create a stack snippet. I have done so and the design is correct. How do I get a single panel to only show? That being, if I click on View 1, the Overview panel goes away and View 1 panel appears? I know there is some things you can do for an accordion style but I'm not sure how that helps me in this case :( Thanks Tieson!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more layer of panels

```
<div class="container-fluid main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#overview" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="overview" data-parent="#accordion">Overview</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="view1" data-parent="#accordion">View 1</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="view2" data-parent="#accordion">View 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel panel-default collapse in" id="overview">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Overview</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Panel content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel panel-default collapse" id="view1">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">View 1</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Panel content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel panel-default collapse" id="view2">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">View 2</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Panel content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might have to adjust the classes for the inner content if you want to get rid of any extra padding / margin. The only thing you have to know is that bootstrap hides the children of any panels under the data-parent unless they match the data-target of what was just clicked.